# Why does Android Studio is not detecting identifier in settext() method?

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbTmM.jpg)i am stuck in this error the studio is not allowing me to set text().need help.i tried a lot but i wasn't working

Comment: Try file->invalidate caches/restart

Answer (score 0):

File->Invalidate caches/Restart